# Is it possible to solo group dungeons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

First of all, i understand that the name **"group dungeon"** means i should not do it solo.

But i have tried to group up for the banished cells 3x now and every time something went wrong with a *"jump failed, instance full"* message and i am somehow removed from the party if i try to travel to another player in the group.
But thats not my question.

My question is, can a group dungeon be done solo without being overleveled? if its even possible to outlevel the dungeon mobs?

Or does each dungeon have a boss or mechanics that simply require multiple people?
I am a veteran MMO player, so i have done stuff like this in other games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does require really good gear and a lot of experience about your character, but yes, you can solo almost every dungeon in the game by yourself.

However, not every dungeon is doable. For example:

**vWGT (White-Gold-Tower):** You WILL fail at the planar inhibitor, since you have to "juggle" the aggro by activating the pinion. If you do it yourself multiple times, you'll suffer a 10k dot which will annihilate you. You need at least 2 people for the planar inhibitor. Other than that, it's possible. (done with my Magicka NB)

**vFG (Fungal Grotto):** In the middle of the dungeon, you have to fight the spectral ghost (can't remember the name) which will bind you to the ground and will OHKO you if the remaining team can't break through the shield.

**vCoH (Crypt of Hearts):** Basically the same as fungal grotto. You'll be bound to the ground once he uses the ebony sword and your team has to break through the shield. Also, the first boss will put you in a web which you can only survive if you are a tank.

**vCoA (City of Ash):** Horvantud the Fire Maw, the big daedroth, is also not doable alone. He spawns way too many adds. I'm running a magicka NB with an average DPS of 35k - 50k and can't kill it before the adds take me out. I think it's only doable as magplar.

Every other dungeon *(given I didn't forget one with a similar mechanic - im far away from knowing every dungeon since most are uninteresting for me)* is - in theory - doable alone. Of course, a lot of them are still incredibly difficult, and soloing vRoM or one of the more difficult dungeons is - at least in my opinion - completely impossible.

Answer (score 3):

It heavily depends on various encounters, some require interaction between players (e.g. freeing another player from an ability that would kill them). Others can indeed be completed solo, although it might take a while.

Besides that, instanced dungeons are always scaled to the level of the group leader, up to level 50 and Champion 160. Therefore it's not possible to outlevel a dungeon, unless you intentionally group up with a lower level player. However, most encounters don't need you to be in a full group.

Comment: I appreciate the info on the scaling system of dungeons but the other answer had more details about certain dungeons. still + 1 for this